# Transforming json file using jq so data ends up under a common object

Tags: json, jq

I have some json data i get from an API that i need to transform using jq into another json format for later use with ansible as part of an inventory script.

What i have is something like:

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "hostname1",
      "key1": "somevalue1",
      "key2": "somevalue2",
      "key3": "somevalue3"
    },
    {
      "name": "hostname2",
      "key1": "somevalue12",
      "key2": "somevalue22",
      "key3": "somevalue32"
    },
    {
      "name": "hostname3",
      "key1": "somevalue13",
      "key2": "somevalue23",
      "key3": "somevalue33"
    }
  ]
}
```

and i need to transform this to look like this:

```json
{
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {
      "hostname1": {
        "name": "hostname1",
        "key1": "somevalue1",
        "key2": "somevalue2",
        "key3": "somevalue3"
      },
      "hostname2": {
        "name": "hostname2",
        "key1": "somevalue12",
        "key2": "somevalue22",
        "key3": "somevalue32"
      },
      "hostname3": {
        "name": "hostname3",
        "key1": "somevalue13",
        "key2": "somevalue23",
        "key3": "somevalue33"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Things i have not been able to figure out.
If i use something like:

```bash
cat input.json | jq '{_meta: { hostvars: { (.results[].name): (.results[]) } }}'
```

Then _meta and hostvars is repeated for each object in the input and that is not at all what i want, i need a common "header" and then the data under there.

Ideally i would like to also exclude the "name" part in the output since it is already used and duplicated, but this is just a bonus.

Advice on how to do this? or is the filter in jq always run against one object at a time?
I experimented a bit with --slurp but didn't get anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial part is: Take an array of objects and transform it into one (outer) object where the attribute names of that outer object are given by some attribute value of the inner objects. That's the job description for `INDEX(filter)`.

So:

```
{ _meta : { hostvars: ( .results | INDEX(.name) ) } }
```

Comment: Do you think if the title contained something like "forming an index from an array with JQ," more people might find this question in the future?

Comment: You can try, but I cannot read the mind of people in the future. :-)

Comment: Yes this solves my immediate problem, but it would have been nice if INDEX was included in the documentation and honestly the documentation i found was a bit thin. Additionally i have lots of more questions and problems but after spending to far too much time on jq to figure out how to do a simple select distinct over the data and the a something like a subquery or foreach loop using those values (something like a parent/child structure) i will probably solve it in some other way

Comment: @TJ: The learning curve for jq is indeed quite steep. I have yet problems wrapping my head around the filter/generator paradigm of jq. Nevertheless I think it's worth it because jq can solve quite a lot complicated transformations in a compact format as opposed to procedural languages.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.results[]` twice will iterate over the same list twice, giving you the cartesian product of each host with each of the other objects ( 3 x 3 = 9 ). You need to reference it once!

You can do something like below. The key to the logic is forming an array of objects, firstly by making the key name as `.name` and the value as the whole sub-object inside.

Once you have the array, you can un-wrap into a comma-separated list of objects using `add`.

```
{ _meta : { hostvars: ( ( .results | map( { ( .name ) : . } ) | add ) ) } }
```

Demo - [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/beVIhddGwdM)

Comment: Ok, so i end up with something like a cross join in sql

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach using `from_entries` could be:

```bash
jq '.results | map({key: .name, value: .}) | {_meta: {hostvars: from_entries}}'
```

```json
{
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {
      "hostname1": {
        "name": "hostname1",
        "key1": "somevalue1",
        "key2": "somevalue2",
        "key3": "somevalue3"
      },
      "hostname2": {
        "name": "hostname2",
        "key1": "somevalue12",
        "key2": "somevalue22",
        "key3": "somevalue32"
      },
      "hostname3": {
        "name": "hostname3",
        "key1": "somevalue13",
        "key2": "somevalue23",
        "key3": "somevalue33"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PSLBjRVS-gS)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to take advantage of jq pipes.

```
cat input.json | jq '{ _meta : { hostvars : (.results | map({key : .name, value :  del(. | .name) }) | from_entries) }}'
```

Map these results as if they were entries to a new set of entries where the key is `.name`, also removing the `.name` from `.value` as you do so:

```
.results | map({key : .name, value :  del(. | .name) })
```

Then, form an object from the entries:

```
... | from_entries
```

**NOTE:** See Inian's answer for why the array syntax used by the OP does not work.